# LU Decomposition of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently working with a practice problem in which we are asked to find the $LU$ factorization of some matrix $A$, given below:
$$
  A= \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 4 & 7 \\
    3 & 6 & 10 \\
    3 & 6 & 10 \\
   \end{pmatrix}
$$

In the first step, I added $-2$ of the first row to the second, $-3$ of the first row to the third, and $-3$ of the first row to the forth to give the matrix:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

In the second step, I added $-1$ of the second row to the third row, and $-1$ of the second row to the fourth row, to give the matrix $U$:
$$
   U = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Given these steps, I determined the matrix $L$ to be:

$$
   L= \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    -3 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
    -3 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
However, although the answer $U$ was found to be correct, the answer $L$ was given the following form:
$$
   L= \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    3 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
However, I don't understand why all of the terms that I found to be negative are positive in the given answer. Can anyone help me figure it out? Thanks!

<sub>(Note: this is not homework, but independent study.)</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using notation from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix), you obtained that
$$L_{24}(-1)L_{23}(-1)L_{14}(-3)L_{13}(-3)L_{12}(-2)A = U$$

so
$$A = L_{12}(-2)^{-1}L_{13}(-3)^{-1}L_{14}(-3)^{-1}L_{23}(-1)^{-1}L_{24}(-1)^{-1}U = L_{12}(2)L_{13}(3)L_{14}(3)L_{23}(1)L_{24}(1)U$$

where $L = L_{12}(2)L_{13}(3)L_{14}(3)L_{23}(1)L_{24}(1)$ is lower triangular with unit diagonal.

Applying these transformations in order to the identity matrix $I$ yields the correct $L$.

Comment: Is it always the case that $L_{ij}(-C)^{-1}$ is equal to $L_{ij}(C)$ where $C$ is any real number?

Comment: @erfx Yes. The inverse of adding $-C$ times $i$-th row to $j$-th row is adding $C$ times $i$-th row to $j$-th row.

Comment: @erfx I messed up the ordering of the elementary matrices, it should be fixed now.